# How do i make this popup appear using PHP if the user input is invalid?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've been figuring out how to show this popup using PHP if the user enters existing username cause our teacher require us to use popUp instead of alert. I have already set the visibility property in css of that popup to "Hidden";

```
<div class="popup">
    <div class="popup-header">
        <span>Wrong Credentials</span>
        <button class="close-button">×</button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="popup-content">
        <p>Invalid username or password</p>
    </div>
    <div class="popup-buttons">
        <button class="cancel-button">Close</button>
       
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP CODE AS OF THE MOMENT, the user validation works well the alert should just be changed to popup.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $pass = $_POST['password'];

  $query = "SELECT * FROM tbluseraccount WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password ='".$pass."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
    echo "<script>
      alert('Invalid Credentials');
      // should do the logic of showing the popUp here
    </script>";  

  } else {
    echo "<script>
    alert('Success');
    window.location.href ='mainpage.php';
    </script>";
  }
}
?>


THANK YOU FOR ANSWERING!
```

i have tried this before

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
    echo "<style>.popup { display: block; }</style>";  
} else {
    echo "<script>
        alert('Success');
        window.location.href = 'mainpage.php';
    </script>";
}
```

Comment: Your teacher perhaps wants/needs to explain the importance of using prepared statements with your SQL rather than focusing on popups - the above is wide open to sql injection. It is not clear how you are submitting/sending this form data to php - is it via regular form or ajax?

Comment: In addition to the sql vulnerability you appear also to be storing the user's passwords as `plain text` within the database. You should `hash` the passwords when added to the db and use `password_verify` to determine if the password is correct

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be more of a css problem than a php problem from how you describe it... but to be sure I should see the css code.

Let me explain better: visibility and display are two distinct CSS properties

so if you used visibility:hidden in your css you should replace display:block with visibility: visible;

like this:

```
<?php //<==== remove this
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
    //change this:
    //echo "<style>.popup { display: block; }</style>";  
    //width this(i leave display:block; too maybe redundant or not it depends on your css):
    echo "<style>.popup { display: block; visibility:visible!important; }</style>";  
} else {
    echo "<script>
        alert('Success');
        window.location.href = 'mainpage.php';
    </script>";
}
```